# Android - Edit and Delete item from Table SqlLite c#

Tags: c#, android, sql, visual-studio, xamarin

My `C#` Android app I am developing takes the user input and add it to a database, then in another `Activity`, it displays the user input with an option to edit his input again.

So I have 2 activities and 1 public class which links them together. I am using SQL to save the user input into a database (Main and First activity) then (in the second activity) it retrieves the saved value (which is the user input) from the public database (located in the public class called `Class1`) and displays it in a listview.

At this point everything is fine, now I want to display a button in the second activity in case the user wants to edit his input then it edits the old input to the new user input in the database and finally, it saves the new input to the database. Also, I want to have another button in the second activity which deletes user input in case the user changed his mind and want to delete his old input and also commit this delete to the public database in `Class1`.

I searched online for how to achieve that but found nothing. I know it is gonna be a simple solution but I am not able to discover it.

**Class1 (the public class)**

```
public class Class1
{
    public static string dpPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "user.db3");
    public static LoginTable tbl = new LoginTable();
}

public class LoginTable
{

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_Id")]

    public int id { get; set; } 

    [MaxLength(15)]

    public string quantity { get; set; }

    public LoginTable()
    {

    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
Add.Click += delegate
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(Class1.dpPath);
    db.CreateTable<LoginTable>();
    Class1.tbl.quantity = edittext.Text;
    db.Insert(Class1.tbl);
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Success", ToastLength.Short).Show();
};
```

**Second Activity**

```
Edit.Click += delegate // Here is the EDIT button
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(Class1.dpPath);
    db.CreateTable<Class1.LoginTable>();
    decimal input = decimal.Parse(newdata.Text);
    Toast.MakeText(context, "Success", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    Class1.tbl.quantity = input.ToString();
    db.Update(Class1.tbl);
};

Delete.Click += delegate // the DELETE button
{
    //Don't know what to write
};
```

Please help me to find a solution.. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just `db.Delete(Class1.tbl);`?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza Yea not working nor the Edit button is working.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza `SQL-net-pcl`

Comment: Both should be working than.  Any exception thrown?

Comment: No exception thrown, just no result. I should not see the user input displayed but it is, nothing is changed after clicking the delete button. What would you do to edit the input in the database ?. Write new code if you want.

Comment: But, what results are you expecring for?  A database change will only modify the table data. Why _you should not see the user input displayed_?  I couldn't understanding what's going on here.

Comment: Yea i know, I should see after refreshing that the user input has been removed, a specific text will be displayed instead of it in the textview